# jQuery datepicker not working properly after append

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am appending row to table add new field but datepicker not working properly.May be its coz of multiple datepicker.i just need datepicker started from current date and next will be start from same date selected on first one.

```
var mydate = new Date();
jQuery(document).on('focus', ".datefrom", function () {
    jQuery(this).datepicker({
        format: 'dd-mm-yy',
        minDate: new Date()
    }).on('dateSelected', function (e, date)
    {
        mydate = date;
    });
});
jQuery(document).on('focus', ".datetill", function () {
    jQuery(this).datepicker({
        format: 'dd-mm-yy',
        minDate: mydate
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Here the snapshot:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0iy9.png)

fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/3oyxc97g/16/

Answer (score 0):

Initiate the second datepicker when the date from the first was selected

```
   var mydate = new Date();
jQuery(document).on('focus', ".datefrom", function() {
  jQuery(this).datepicker({
    format: 'dd-mm-yy',
    minDate: new Date()
  }).on('changeDate', function() {
    mydate = this.value;
    dates = mydate.split('-');
    mydate = dates[1]+'-'+dates[0]+'-'+dates[2];

    jQuery(".datetill").datepicker('destroy').datepicker({
      format: 'dd-mm-yy',
      startDate: new Date(mydate)
    });
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3oyxc97g/31/

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var mydate=new Date();  
jQuery(document).on('focus',".datefrom", function(){ 
jQuery(this).datepicker({ 
      format : 'dd-mm-yyyy',
      autoclose :  true,
      todayHighlight : true,
      startDate : new Date()
}).on('changeDate', function(ev)
{
  mydate=jQuery('.datefrom').val();
});
});
......
```

Comment: @Gulshan glad to help you:):)

Comment: doesn/t seem to work in jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/3oyxc97g/35/ , my answer works

Comment: check code properly @madalin ivascu ..what i want and what u did.. i want first picker started from today and next picker started from first picker selected date.but thanks for your help..u did alot :)